# Google Sheets - Python Access timeout

Tags: python, json, google-sheets-api

I'am trying to read and write from and to a Google Spreadsheet. I've found this tutorial online, which seems to work for a lot of people:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=youtube_python_google_sheets

What I did so far:

- Created the credentials according to the guide and downloaded the .json file
- Shared a copy of the Legislator Spreadsheet (now in my google Drive) with the client e-mail.
- I received an E-Mail after sharing that the message wasn't delivered as the service account domain wasn't found.
- I adopted the code

  ```
  import gspread
  from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

  scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
  creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
  client = gspread.authorize(creds)

  sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017", scope)
  list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
  print(list_of_hashes)
  ```

The client_secret.json file is in the same folder as the project.

[image]

But when I run the code, I get the following error:

[image]

The Japanese says:　”It was not possible to connect because the connected callee did not respond correctly even after a certain period of time. Or the connected host failed because the connected host did not respond.”

There seems to be a problem with the log in, but I have no clue how to fix it.
Also, while researching, I found that the `scope` part is always different. Can someone explain to me what needs to be insert there?
Does anyone have an experience with it? Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're OAuthclientID is valid and you've enabled Sheets API in your Google Dev Console.

Then, try to use the Sheetsv4 scope instead. I remember encountering some errors when I used the scope for v3. So hopefully, this helps you:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint

scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('NAME_OF_GOOGLE_SHEET').sheet1

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

# get all the records
result = sheet.get_all_records()

pp.pprint(result)
```